# How do I start a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I would like to start a bounty for the question:

[How to calculate the integral of a product of a spherical Hankel function with associated Legendre polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4257140/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-a-product-of-a-spherical-hankel-function-with-a)

Below the questions and existing comments, there is a link titled: "Question eligible for bounty since Sep 24, 2021". When I click on the link I get to a help page about bounties. Part of it says the following:

"How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50-point increments. You can also choose from a list of bounty reasons to help other users understand why you’re dissatisfied with any current answers to the question. If you need to describe something in more detail, there’s also optional, additional custom text that will be displayed with the bounty reason."

However, I cannot see the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of the question. Am I blind or just stupid? Maybe it needs to be made more prominent. The link that does exist says that the question has been eligible for bounty for months, so it's not a question of eligibility.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Including more of the context of how you got this problem would probably help get an answer. How does this come out of scattering from multiple spheres? Also, do you have any of the previous stuff you tried that got too complicated? (At this level of complexity, I think screenshots would be ok if you don't want to TeX it out.)

Comment: If you add the above, ping me and I'll bounty it for you. It's a good question.

Comment: I've expanded on the context in the questions. Some of the formulae I've been attempting to use can be seen in previous edits of the question (I had removed them because I felt the question lost the necessary brevity to attract interest). I've also thought of a potential useful first step that I've added at the bottom of the question as a progress update.

Comment: Thanks for starting a bounty, Alexander.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get an answer. I'll promote this in the Pearl Dive also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Meta Stackexchange Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> If you have already offered a bounty on the question before, the minimum offer is double your last offer (see below).

You previously offered a bounty for 200 reputation on the question (as you can see on your [offered bounties list on you profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/760114/chris?tab=bounties&sort=offered)), so a new bounty would have to be for at least 400 reputation.  Since you currently don't have 400 reputation you can't start a bounty on this question right now.

I believe that the "Question eligible for bounty since..." link that you see appears only if you have insufficient reputation to offer a bounty on the question.  If you can offer a bounty, then the "Start a bounty" link appears in its place.

Comment: Thanks, I never would have guessed this was a rule!